# Scroll-Position in HTML5 section

Tags: html, scroll

In my PHP/HTML5 Document, I include an HTML5 section, I need this to deploy a table with a static header, this works fine for me.

My problem is, a table is a form with checkboxes. If I click the checkbox, I create make some new lines with info.

The click on the checkbox creates a side reload after the reload I need to scroll to the last position.

Without the section, it works fine. I save the window position I a hidden form element and after reloading, in the event "windows.onload" I scroll to the value:

```
function finance_submit(){
    document.forms.finance.winpos.value=window.scrollY;
    finance.submit();
    return;
}   

window.onload = function()
{
    window.scrollTo(0, document.forms.finance.winpos.value);
}
```

Now I need to get the scroll position in from the section and then I need to scroll the section to the value.

Here the pure HTML code from the section:

```css
<style type="text/css">
    html, body{
  margin:25px;
  padding:0;
height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:1000px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #FFFFCC;
  color: #000;
  padding: 1px 2px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 2px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -2px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}

.neutral {
  background: #FFFFCC;
  
}

.red {
  background: red;
  
}

.orange {
  background: orange; 
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

#spalte1 { width: 80px; }
#spalte2 { width: 300px; }
#spalte3 { width: 350px; }
#spalte4 { width: 110px; }
#spalte5 { width: 110px; }
#spalte6 { width: 110px; }
#spalte7 { width: 110px; }
#spalte8 { width: 110px; }
#spalte9 { width: 88px; }
#spalte10 { width: 108px; }
#spalte11 { width: 88px; }
#spalte12 { width: 103px; }
#spalte13 { width: 50px; }
#spalte14 { width: 50px; }


</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <title>HTML table pure CSS fixed header by dPixie</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
        <th id='spalte1'>Nummer<div>Nummer</div></th>
          <th id='spalte2'>Kunde<div>Kunde</div></th>
          <th id='spalte3'>Name<div>Name</div></th>
          <th id='spalte4'>Vertr.Termin<div>Vertr.Termin</div></th>
          <th id='spalte5'>Liefertermin<div>Liefertermin</div></th>
          <th id='spalte6'>Überg.Termin<div>Überg.Termin</div></th>
          <th id='spalte7'>Rechn.Leg.<div>Rechn.Leg.</div></th>
          <th id='spalte8'>Auftrags Sum<div>Auftrags Sum</div></th><th id='spalte9'>Ext.Leist.<div>Ext.Leist.</div></th>
          <th id='spalte10'>Auftr.Budg.<div>Auftr.Budg.</div></th><th id='spalte11'>Int.Kosten<div>Int.Kosten</div>
          </th><th id='spalte12'>Ertrag<div>Ertrag</div></th>
          <th id='spalte13'>%<div>%</div></th>
          <th id='spalte14'>Details<div>Details</div></th>  
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please also include the relevant part of your page source.

Comment: Is this related to PHP, other than being a PHP file?

Comment: Do you really need to re-render the whole thing just because of a check box?